# Running Eclipse Che through Docker on Windows causes error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, eclipse-che

I am trying to run Eclipse Che on Windows using Docker with this command (powershell):

```
> docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/EclipseChe:/data eclipse/che:rc start
```

When I run this I get the following output

```
INFO: (che cli): rc - using docker 19.03.8 / docker4mac
INFO: (che config): Generating che configuration...
INFO: (che config): Customizing docker-compose for running in a container
INFO: (che start): Preflight checks
         mem (1.5 GiB):           [OK]
         disk (100 MB):           [OK]
         port 8080 (http):        [AVAILABLE]
         conn (browser => ws):    [OK]
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
/scripts/base/library.sh: line 333: 1: unbound variable
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am using eclipse/che:rc because I get the following error when trying to use latest:

> Error response from daemon: manifest for eclipse/che:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: Pls follow the guide
[How to run Che locally](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/running-che-locally/)

Comment: it seems you're using waaay old Che version..

Answer (score 0):

```
docker exec -it fakeagent-8080 sh
apk update
apk add curl
```

Warning will disappear, but still showing 404.